# How to implement a yahoo login in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift

i am in trouble, anyone can suggest how to implement a yahoo login in a swift language.
from here i have downloaded a objective c library for yahoo login [Yahoo SDK library Objective - C](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-objc)

Comment: That repository has a demo. Maybe you can find the code in there.

Comment: It has a demo that is in objective-c not swift OP is asking specifically for swift.

Comment: Here is the example :https://github.com/amitdagar/YahooLogin_ContactList

Answer (score -1):

You can still use a Objective-c library and combine with the swift objective c bridging header

Read more:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html